# Too many rcuos and rcuob processes in my VM

Tags: kernel, virtual-machine, cpu, vmware, thread

I am running `CentOS 7.2 (3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64)` as VMware guest with 2 cpu and 6 GB RAM on my Lenevo W540 iCore 7 having 32 GB RAM.

I see 128 processes each for rcuos and rcuob in my VM. This does not sound right as these processes should be equal to number of cores in a system.

I am noticing my VM freeze occasionally.

Is there a way to limit the number of rcuos and rcuob processes equal to number of CPUs.

I reduced number of CPU in VM Guest to 1 and still the number of rcuos and rcuob are 128 each.

I then added `maxcpus=0` as a kernel boot parameter and that reduced the number of `rcuos` and `rcuob` to 1 each but then I need more cores assigned to the VM. My application performance reduces by 40% if I just use one core.

Answer (score 2):

My knowledge about Linux Kernel is very limited and and how to tweak it. I kept googling after I posted and stumbled upon another kernel boot parameter nr_cpus [here](http://www.crashcourse.ca/wiki/index.php/CPUs_and_SMP) and after I set this to 2 (Number of CPUs) in my VM, I now only see 2 rcuos and rcuoc processes.

This is what worked for me.

Edit

```
/etc/default/grub
```

and add

```
nr_cpus=2
```

in the line for GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX. And then ran

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

and rebooted and now instead of 128 each processes for rcuos and rcuoc, I only now see 2 processes each.

```
$ ps aux | grep rcu
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    23:04   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    23:04   0:00 [rcuob/0]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    23:04   0:00 [rcuob/1]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        R    23:04   0:00 [rcu_sched]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    23:04   0:00 [rcuos/0]
root        13  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    23:04   0:00 [rcuos/1]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to solve this problem in vmware:

Turn off the vm.

Edit settings > Options > Advanced > Memory / CPU Hotplug

In "CPU Hot Plug", disable "CPU hot plug for this virtual machine."

Power on.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Too many kernel threads of this type is a bug that is addressed in https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1404313 by errata https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2016-2574.html and fixed in `kernel-3.10.0-514` or later. RedHat published this in November 2016, so I'm certain it is by now available in CentOS.

Update the kernel and reboot. You should see the normal number of `rcous` threads. In my case, normal was actually 0, down from about 95 on a 6-core VM.